# Run something that requires root from a system application

Tags: android-source, fuse

I'm trying to run fuse from an app that runs under the system user.

using the following code in `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
```

and the following in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<manifest ...
    coreApp="true"
    android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">
```

The app is located inside the AOSP code, under `/packages/apps/`.

When I run it, I get:

> fuse: bad mount point `/path/to/folder': Permission denied

so, I figured that I need root access in order for it to work, because it works when it is run from `init.rc`, which can run with root credentials.

Is there a way for me to gain root access in a system app? or somehow make it work without really granting it root privileges? given that I have a full access to the AOSP code.

I tried running:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

but I get:

> System.err: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [su] Working Directory: null Environment: null

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem?

Comment: @MichaelB Nope.. I eventually ran a c++ program from init.rc that did all the fuse stuff for me

Comment: Thank you! I came up with a similar solution. ;)